# Apache Reverse Proxy with SSL handling

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, reverse-proxy, mod-ssl

I am trying to use apache as a reverse proxy, and to off load SSL processing from the underlying Node Js application.  I have the configuration defined but it doesn't look as though the system is trying to perform the reverse proxy portion. For instance inside of ssl_error_log I see the following:

> [error] File does not exist: /etc/httpd/htdocs

which looks to happen whenever I access the root of the site.  I am not certain but it looks as though it is trying to serve the page out of that directory.  My apache config is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName portal.somewhere.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/wildcard.somewhere.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/wildcard.somewhere.com.key


    ProxyPass /  http://12.7.20.78:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://12.7.20.78:80/

    ErrorLog logs/portal.somewhere.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/portal.somewhere.com-access_log common

</VirtualHost>
```

When I ssh onto 12.7.20.78 and run tcpdump i see no activity reaching that machine.  For debugging purposes, I was able to flip out the above config for one running on port 80 (no ssl):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName portal.somewhere.com
    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyPass /  http://12.7.20.78:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://12.7.20.78:80/

    ErrorLog logs/portal.somewhere.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/portal.somewhere.com-access_log common

</VirtualHost>
```

When running this config, the system forwards requests and serves pages from the machine: http://12.7.20.78 without any issues.  This is confirmed by tcpdump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there were two config set up on 443 causing the confusion. Removed the old one.